# Should I be using a SWIG typemap for ruby Fixnum -> matlab mwSize?

Tags: c, ruby, swig, matlab-deployment, matlab-engine

I'm trying to update a project which uses SWIG to build an interface from ruby to matlab. The matlab C-API has changed and now I get the following error at runtime.

> `mxCreateDoubleMatrix_730': Expected argument 0 of type mwSize, but got Fixnum 20 (TypeError)

I found mwSize defined in tmwtypes.h, which was not being included in the SWIG interface file:

```
tmwtypes.h:typedef int mwSize;
tmwtypes.h:typedef size_t    mwSize;         /* unsigned pointer-width integer */
```

But, if I add tmwtypes.h to the include section of the SWIG interface, I still get the TypeError and if I add it to both the include and the parse section, I get the following compile error:

> Error: CPP #error ""This code must be compiled using a 2's complement representation for signed integer values"". Use the -cpperraswarn option to continue swig processing.

Giving up on tmwtypes.h, my solution is to add the following to the SWIG interface file.

```
%typemap(in) mwSize {
   $1 = NUM2INT($input);
}
```

You can look at the complete SWIG interface file at:
https://github.com/morrifeldman/matlab-ruby/blob/master/ext/matlab_api/matlab_api.i

After adding this typemap, the program compiles and seems to work perfectly.

I have two related questions I would like answered:

1. Is the correct solution to the TypeError I am having with mwSize.  Should I try something else instead?
2. I thought that including tmwtypes.h would fix my problem.  Why didn't it work?

For reference, I'm using OSX Mountain Lion with Xcode 4.5.2. The Makefile is calling gcc-4.2.  'gcc-4.2 --version' gives 'i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1'

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to replace the `typemap` with:

```
typedef size_t    mwSize;
```

However, I can't offer any insight into what is going on.